# How to stop Scaffold-DbContext to create symlink like models in the scaffolding project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

When I scaffold a Context using a project, but specifying an output path for the models and the Context, for some reason it starts creating a symlink like file in the project used for scaffolding.

Creating these symlinks is really time consuming (in this project it took like 10 minutes) and I don't want it!

To give some context, the creation of the actual models (in the specified folder) and the context took like 30 seconds!

This is the command i have used: 
`Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "a connection string" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Something -OutputDir ..\SomeProject.Models\Database -ContextDir ..\SomeProject.DataProject\Contexts -Context MyContext -Force`

In the image, on the left there are the symlinks and on the right the actual files.
[This is what the symlinks are like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1unCN.png)

How can I disable this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: 29/05/2020

The symlinks originate from the .csproj file, and looks like this:

`<Compile Include="..\OtherFolder\MySharedClass.cs" Link="MySharedClass.cs" />`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Well, to avoid this you can use the command line of ef-core, outside on Visual Studio. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold